# MYSQL - limit between results for fast search in ranges

Tags: mysql, range, between

I have two tables in MYSQL where table2 contains ranges of serial numbers (unique) with 17 digits (varchar 17) and table1 contains serial values (same format as ranges)
ex:

```
table 1:
serial_id   seial
1           12345678123456799

table 2:
range id      date              start                end
1             2012-01-01        12345678123456789    12345678123456999
2             2012-01-01        12345678123457000    12345678123457099
3             2012-01-01        12345678123457100    12345678123457199
```

I want to find range ids that each serial belong to it.the simplest query that can be used is:

```
select *
from table1,table2
where table1.serial  between table2.start and table2.end
```

but I want to optimize it to run faster with below facts : 
the serials and ranges are unique and so each serial may belong to **one and only one range**. so it is not necessary to search other ranges when one range contains the serial. 
first 11 digits of each range are the same. for example one ranges can be from 12345678120000000 to 12345678129999999. 
serials and ranges are ordered by date and it is more likely to find ranges in early dates. serials are about 6000000 records and ranges are about 100000 records.

any idea for better query?

Comment: Can you show us your real query from these tables? I asked this question because your query returns 6m records and it is useless in real world. It will allow us to provide better answer.

Comment: @Msf-vpt : my real query is written above. I have sold ranges of product batches that have serial numbers. my ranges are sold batches and I want to search used batches in sold batches. after this query, I can find unused serials, delay from sale to use, faster seller, and more information.

Comment: Provide CREATE table statements for all relevant tables and the result of the EXPLAIN. And don't use evil `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit challenging to speed up.  Here is one method that I've used with IP address ranges:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.range_id
        from table2 t2
        where t2.start <= t.serial
        order by t2.start desc
        limit 1
       ) as range_id
from table1 t1;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `table2(start, range_id)`.

Note:  this does not check the end of the range.  For that, I would add another join . . . although this (unhappily) requires materializing a subquery:

```
select *
from (select t1.*,
             (select t2.range_id
              from table2 t2
              where t2.start <= t.serial
              order by t2.start desc
              limit 1
             ) as range_id
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.range_id = t2.range_id and t2.end >= t.serial;
```

The additional join want an index on `table2(range_id, end)`.

Comment: thanks Gordon, but serial may be greater than more than one start and "limit 1" will select first one. if the first range doesn't contain the serial, the result would be incorrect. for example : 5 in ranges (1-3,4-7,8-10) in the first and second range 5 is greater than start. but second one contains it.

Comment: @user3833757 . . . The `order by` in the subquery should be descending (as it now is).

Answer (score 0):

I think by a little change in data model, a big performance improvement will happen.
By adding rangeid column to table1 as foreign key.

```
table 1:
serial_id   seial              rangeid
1           12345678123456799  1
```

Then write following query:

```
select *
from table1 join table2 using(rangeid);
```

And if that change is impossible you can use like operator as below:

```
select *
from table1 join table2
on(table2.start like concat(left(table1.serial,12),'%'))
where table1.serial  between table2.start and table2.end;
```

table2.start column must be indexed.

Edit:
And increase the number "12" to max possible number according the relation between **serial** field and **start** field.

Comment: thanks, the first one cant be reached because serials are logged without any range info. the second idea took more time to run for me.

Comment: @user3833757 , Can you tell how much time it takes?

Comment: @user3833757 Increase the number "12" to max possible number.

Comment: I test it for sample of 1000 serial and 120000 ranges, simple query :  3.109 sec. (+ 20.766 sec. network)   your query: 3.359 sec. (+ 20.844 sec. network)

Comment: @user3833757 thank you. Did you create an index on table2.start?

Comment: @user3833757 It is strange! Declare table2.start as primary key and test again. PKs are very faster than normal index in mysql.